# jQuery hiding pagination elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, hide

I'm using twitter bootstrap. What I want to achieve is, when there are lots of pages to place "..." button inside pagination and every time user clicks it add 5 more pages to pagination container.

Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/sqd12tr3/ As you see there are 58 pages. What I want to achieve is to show 5 pages and ... button. When I click it adds 5 more pages. So on and at the end, when it achieves 58 `...` button disappears. Another thing is, for example if 10th li is active, pages (`li`s) until active li must be shown by default.

How can I achiieve this result?

Comment: something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/zk5hemju/  Not 100% clear what you want

Comment: numerous plugins avaliable for pagers, suggest you look into them

Comment: @charlietfl No. When user enters to the page, the pagination must be like that: 1,2,3,4,5, ... when you press `...` next 5 elements appears but, don't remove previous elements. And when you initialize for the first time look for li with `active` class. All `li`s standing before active must be shown by default.

Comment: get a plugin , no point re inventing the wheel. I could see getting this started and then being asked to keep adding features and behaviors to it.

Comment: Nice set of requirements. Did you try something by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this rather fun to play with.  Thanks for posting.  I added a `<li>` with `class='ellipses'` at the end of the `<ul>` and used the following jQuery:

```
var pages = $('.pagination li').not('.ellipses');
var pagesVisible = 0;
var show = function(numToShow) {
    numToShow += 1;
    $('.pagination li').removeAttr('style');
    $('.pagination li:nth-child(n + ' + numToShow + ')').not('.ellipses').hide();

    var hiddenPages = $('.pagination li[style="display: none;"]');
    if (hiddenPages.length === 0)
    {
        $('.ellipses').remove();
    }
    pagesVisible = pages.length - hiddenPages.length;
};

$('.ellipses').click(function() {
    show(pagesVisible + 5);
});

var activePage = $('.pagination li.active').index();
var numToShow = activePage + (5 - (activePage % 5));
show(numToShow);
```

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sqd12tr3/1/) on JSFiddle.